# How to define an intent as a URL

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working with NFC an Android.

Actually, when tapping the NFC tag I would like to send the user to a URL whose only task is to allow permissions on their smartphone.

I am using NFCtools.

At the moment I have tried intent://#Intent;scheme=http;package=android.settings.CAST_SETTINGS;end as a URL but it is registered but not executed.

Is it possible to send the user to a URL which would activate `android.settings.CAST_SETTINGS` on my phone?

Or is there another easy way to activate the `cast_settings` (smart view @ samsung for instance) without installing an app on the phone?

Comment: We appreciate you do it for your grandma, but you don't need to include into the post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the whole no-installation part...but...

Create an NfedMessage with a URI type [NdefRecord](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html#createUri(java.lang.String)).

Register the custom URI in your intent filter to kick off a specific activity, similar to this [method](https://medium.com/@gun0912/android-start-activity-by-custom-url-scheme-eada62fdf9eb).